# Python Parsing multiple JSON objects into one object

Tags: python, json, csv

I currently have a json file that looks like this....

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "tag": "cashandequivalents",
        "value": 10027000000.0
    },
    { 
        "tag": "shortterminvestments",
        "value": 101000000.0
    },
    {
        "tag": "accountsreceivable",
        "value": 4635000000.0
    },
    {
        "tag": "netinventory",
        "value": 1386000000.0
    }...
```

but what I am trying to get to is this

```
{ 
    "cashandequivalents": 10027000000.0, 
    "shortterminvestments":101000000.0 , 
    "accountsreceivable":4635000000.0,  
    "netinventory":1386000000.0
}
```

I just don't know how to go about this.

---

Maybe there is an easier way, but this seems the most logical to me because  the next step is `writer.writerow` to csv

So eventually the csv will look like

```
cashandequivalents | shortterminvestments | accountsreceivable | netinventory
100027000000         101000000000           46350000000          13860000000
###########          ############           ###########          ...........
```

(`writer.writeheader` will be done outside of the loop so I am only writing the values, not the "tags")

Thanks

Comment: `combined = {item['tag']: item['value'] for item in a['data']}` where `a` is your initial structure. That's a dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

A naive solution:

```
import json

json_data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "tag": "cashandequivalents",
            "value": 10027000000.0
        },
        {
            "tag": "shortterminvestments",
            "value": 101000000.0
        },
        {
            "tag": "accountsreceivable",
            "value": 4635000000.0
        },
        {
            "tag": "netinventory",
            "value": 1386000000.0
        }
    ]
}

result = dict()
for entry in json_data['data']:
    result[entry['tag']] = entry['value']

print json.dumps(result, indent=4)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "shortterminvestments": 101000000.0, 
    "netinventory": 1386000000.0, 
    "accountsreceivable": 4635000000.0, 
    "cashandequivalents": 10027000000.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and cleanest way to do this is with a dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {
 "data": [
  {
  "tag": "cashandequivalents",
  "value": 10027000000.0
  },
  { 
  "tag": "shortterminvestments",
  "value": 101000000.0
  },
  {
  "tag": "accountsreceivable",
  "value": 4635000000.0
   },
   {
   "tag": "netinventory",
   "value": 1386000000.0
   }
 ]
}
newDict = {i['tag']: i['value'] for i in d['data']}

# {'netinventory': 1386000000.0, 'shortterminvestments': 101000000.0, 'accountsreceivable': 4635000000.0, 'cashandequivalents': 10027000000.0}
```

---

This iterates through the `list` that is contained within the `"data"` key of your original `dictionary` and creates a new one inline with the key being the `tag` value of each and the value being the `value` for each  during the iterations.